# i made a home page to be redirected after users are logged in with react, so after logging in i was only redirected to empty page but not home

Tags: reactjs, react-router

the image here includes my code from app

My code is in this picture. I made a home page to be redirected after the users are logged in , so after logging in I was only redirected to an empty page but not to home ,I suspect there are some mistakes in my app rendering login , could someone please help, thank you

Comment: No any image added

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZG8J.png

Comment: I also got a warning in the console   Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
    at AuthContextProvider

Comment: Please, no images of your code. You should post properly formatted and readable code snippets. We can't help debug code we can't see. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66289122/how-to-create-a-protected-route/66289280#66289280

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.