# Uncaught Error: useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component. - What is it that I am doing wrong?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, authentication, react-router

I am trying to create an authenticated route and I did the following but this throws an error saying

```
2Transition.js:251 Uncaught Error: useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.
at invariant (Transition.js:251:1)
at useNavigate (TransitionGroup.js:123:1)
at App (App.tsx:27:1)
at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:17415:1)
at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:22173:1)
at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:23654:1)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:5344:1)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:5393:1)
at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:5456:1)
at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:28649:1)
```

What is it that I am doing wrong?

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";


function App() {
     const navigate = useNavigate();
     return(
           <BrowserRouter>
                 <Routes>
                        <Route
                           path={APP_ROUTES.DASHBOARD}
                            element={
                             isUserLoggedIn() ? <Dashboard /> : 
                                                <>pp{navigate(APP_ROUTES.LOGIN)}</>
                            }
                        />
                 </Routes>
          </BrowserRouter>
     )
}
```

What would be the best way to add a couple of authenticated routes?

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

The `App` component is rendering the router that provides the routing context that the `useNavigate` hook needs.

## Solution

Move `BrowserRouter` higher in the ReactTree so that it can provide a routing context to components below it. Wrapping `App` component with a router is correct if you want to use any `react-router-dom` hooks ***in*** the `App` component.

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

...

```
import { Routes, Route, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route
        path={APP_ROUTES.DASHBOARD}
        element={isUserLoggedIn()
          ? <Dashboard />
          : <>pp{navigate(APP_ROUTES.LOGIN)}</>
        }
      />
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

### Additional Question

> What would be the best way to add a couple of authenticated routes?

See [How to Create a Protected Route](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66289280/8690857)

Comment: For, this solution people also use it for `<HashRouter>`. Thanks this solution help me

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use useNavigate() inside the App's component that is not inside a BrowserRouter because the BrowserRouter is inside the App's component and not around.

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, you are using a hook in a component that isn't inside the `<BrowserRouter>.`

A potential solution would be to build a ProtectedRoute component

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ children }) => {
  if (! isUserLoggedIn()) {
    return <Navigate to={APP_ROUTES.LOGIN} replace />;
  }

  return children;
};
```

and wrap your route around it:

```
       <Route
          path="home"
          element={
            <ProtectedRoute>
              <Dashboard />
            </ProtectedRoute>
          }
        />
```

Good blog post here: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-router-private-routes/