# Redirect Router after loggedin

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Am trying to Redirect router to `"/"`, without login it set to `Landing.jsx`, After login needs to redirect to `Homepage.jsx` which is also in same route `"/"`. tried `useNavigate`, Its redirecting to `"/"` but it was set to `Landing.jsx`, only after refresh it sets the `Homepage.jsx`. Route method I used is mentioned below. Please help.
The Validate is settedup when logged in was successfull.

```
const validate = localStorage.getItem('userLoggedInDetails');

<Router>
  <Header />
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={validate ? <Homepage /> : <Landing />}></Route>
    <Route path="/login" element={<Login />}></Route>
    <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />}></Route>
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

Comment: Please try to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that includes all the relevant code you are working with. Is something supposed to update the `validate` value to switch from rendering the `Landing` component to the `Homepage` component, or vice versa?

Comment: And where and how are users logging in and getting redirected back to `"/"`? Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66289280/8690857

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using react.

React does not "react" to changes in localStorage. You need to use hooks like useState.

This was an easy enough problem to recreate and so I have created a CodeSandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-bohr-3eqy2o

I would recommend reading the documentation of react to avoid these kinds of issues.

Comment: Thanks. got it. And sure will check the docs

Comment: Could you mark the response as an answer if it helped =)