# How to enable route only for unauthorized users React.js router V5

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm working with React Router V5.

I have implemented my application routes.

- HomeComponent for all users
- LoginComponent only for **not logged in users**.

My issue is when i'm logged in and i go into /login then i stuck on blank page. I want achieve redirection into home component. Login component should be only available

Could you tell me what is wrong with my routes?

```
export const AppRoutes = () => {
  const { currentUser } = useAuth();
  return (
    <Switch>
      {!currentUser.isLoggedIn && <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />}
      <Layout>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
          <Redirect to='/' />
        </Switch>
      </Layout>
    </Switch>
```

Comment: Might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66289122/how-to-create-a-protected-route.

Comment: Your previous question was closed as a duplicate. Please don't repost the same identical question. Edit the existing post to improve the question and explain why it might not be a duplicate. Is there some specific aspect of the duplicate question you've tried and still have some issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Redirect](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect)

```
{!currentUser.isLoggedIn ? <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} /> : <Redirect to="/" />}
```