# React/Typescript conditional routing - Updating from React Router Dom v5 to v6

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I'm a newbie to Typescript and I'm updating our app's react router version from v5 to v6. I'm stuck on how to update this conditional routing wrapper:

```
// v5
import React from "react";
import {
  Redirect,
  RedirectProps,
  Route,
  RouteComponentProps,
  RouteProps,
} from "react-router-dom";

export type ConditionalRouteProps = React.FC<
  RouteProps &
    Partial<RedirectProps> & {
      condition?: boolean;
    }
>;

const ConditionalRoute: ConditionalRouteProps = ({
  component: Component,
  condition = false,
  children,
  ...rest
}) => {
  const toRender = (props: RouteComponentProps): React.ReactElement | null => {
    if (!condition) return <Redirect to={REDIRECT_DESTINATION} />;
    if (Component) return <Component {...props} />;
    return <>{children}</>;
  };

  return <Route {...rest} render={toRender} />;
};

export { ConditionalRoute };
```

I know the render method and Redirect component is scrapped, this is what I've done so far (WIP):

```
//v6
import React from "react";
import { Navigate, NavigateProps, Route, RouteProps } from "react-router-dom";

export type ConditionalRouteProps = React.FC<
  RouteProps &
    Partial<NavigateProps> & {
      condition?: boolean;
    }
>;

const ConditionalRoute: ConditionalRouteProps = ({
  element: Element,
  condition = false,
  children,
  ...rest
}) => {
  return (

<Route {...rest}>
  {!condition ? (
    <Navigate to={REDIRECT_DESTINATION} />
  ) : Element ? (
    <Element />
  ) : (
    <>{children}</>
  )}
</Route>
  );
};

export { ConditionalRoute };
```

and this is the error I'm getting on `<Element />`:
JSX element type 'Element' does not have any construct or call signatures.ts(2604)

This is how to wrapper is being called:

```
const AdminRoute: ConditionalRouteProps = (props) => {
  const { isAdmin } = useContext(UserContext);
  return <ConditionalRoute condition={isAdmin} {...props} />;
};
```

...

```
const TestPage: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Link to="/admin" data-testid="navigateToAdmin">
        Navigate to admin
      </Link>
    </>
  );
};

const TestRoutes: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route
        path="/admin"
        element={<AdminRoute element={() => <h1>Admin Page</h1>} />}
      />
      <Route path="/" element={<TestPage />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};

describe("<AdminRoute />", () => {
  it("should let admin users in", () => {
    const { history } = renderWithProviders(<TestRoutes />, {
      providerProps: { userProviderProps: { isAdmin: true } },
    });

  userEvent.click(screen.getByTestId("navigateToAdmin"));
  expect(history.location.pathname).toEqual("/admin");
  });

  it("should redirect everyone else", () => {
    const { history } = renderWithProviders(<TestRoutes />);

    userEvent.click(screen.getByTestId("navigateToAdmin"));

    expect(screen.queryByText("Admin Page")).not.toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(history.location.pathname).toEqual("/");
  });
});
```

Comment: Could you post the Element you are trying to render?

Comment: Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66289122/how-to-create-a-protected-route/66289280#66289280

Comment: My answer in the above link isn't in Typescript, but the general gist is that in `react-router-dom@6` any "custom route components" are drastically different from their v5 counterparts. You don't render the `Route` component directly, instead either return the `children` prop if wrapping a single element, or an `Outlet` component for nested routes to render their `element` prop into. Your code is overcomplicating things quite a bit and this what is making it difficult to type. If done correctly, your `ConditionalRoute` component doesn't need to take any props.

Comment: Added an example for rending the Element! Thanks @DrewReese - I figured it was a bit overcomplicated as it is now, I'll have a dig into the `Outlet` component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are complicating the route protection a bit. `react-router-dom@6` route rendering works quite differently in v6, we don't directly render a `Route` in *our* components, they are to be rendered into the `Routes` component or directly nested under other `Route` components for route nesting.

I suggest the following implementation:

```
//v6
import React from "react";
import { Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

interface IConditionalRoute = {
  condition: boolean;
};

const ConditionalRoute = ({ condition = false }: IConditionalRoute) => {
  return condition ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to={REDIRECT_DESTINATION} />;
};

export { ConditionalRoute };
```

***Note:** I'm not super strong in Typescript, so I might not have got the syntax completely correct, but I expect the interface/code should get you close to what you would need.*

Usage:

The `AdminRoute` would be rendered on what is called a [layout route](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#layout-routes), a route that renders an `Outlet` and wraps other `Route` components. Omit the `path` prop so the path of the nested routes is what is used for matching/rendering.

```
const AdminRoute: ConditionalRouteProps = () => {
  const { isAdmin } = useContext(UserContext);
  return <ConditionalRoute condition={isAdmin} />;
};

const TestRoutes: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route element={<AdminRoute />}>
        <Route path="/admin" element={<h1>Admin Page</h1>} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/" element={<TestPage />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};
```