# How to use Reactjs with redux to implement an authentication process correctly?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, redux-toolkit

I tried to create an authentication process with ReactJS and Redux/toolkit currently.

When Client enter the page which is required auth, this program would get the value of `isAuth` from `store.authReducer`

```
useEffect(()=>{
 if(!isAuth) navigate("/signin", {replace: true})
},[navigate])
```

the authentication checker is written in the entry point of router

```
useEffect(() => {
dispatch(authenticateAsyncAction());
}, [dispatch]);
```

Suppose, client is logged successfully, and enter any page by the web app element (ex: `<Link to="/user/profile">profile</Link>`), it works well.

But the problem would happen when client enter the route by browser url input field (ex:`https://domain/user/profile`). The default value of `isAuth` is `false`, and `authenticateAsyncAction()` is an `async function`, the navigation will be triggered and redirect page to `/signin` before `isAuth` was changed to `true`.

Is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: Does this help answer your question about implementing route protection? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66289280/8690857 Sub in the "authLogin" value with what you select from your Redux store.

Comment: @DrewReese Actually, I found an official resolution of react-router https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/examples/auth/src/App.tsx#L41-L47

Answer (score 1):

You need to first check for a loading state, which would initially be true. Once the authentication is done, flip the loading state to false and the auth state to true.

Comment: I asked this question in facebook front end community as same time, and I got another answer that suggest me to store the state into `localStorage`

Comment: How are they currently authenticated? You should not put a session cookie for instance in local storage as it's insecure.

You technically could put an `isAuth` boolean in your localstorage, but how would you know if the user is signed out / session has expired?

You could server side render your react app and authenticate on the server and pre-populate that field (I'm imagining that is a much more complex solution than you want to do though).

Comment: You could also make an checkAuth api call (maybe what you're currently doing), where again you'd need to add in a loading state for the isAuth

Comment: Honestly, though you should probably only render most of your components if `isAuth` is true

Comment: The best solution is a loading state and only rendering things the non-static portion on your page after that is resolved (or server-side render the auth - much more complex)

Comment: If you're using `next.js` definitely SSR the user!

Comment: Yeah, I just store `isAuth` in the `localStorage`. In fact, my authState have a validator like  `{ isAuth: boolean, status: 'idle' | 'pending' | 'succeeded' | 'failed'}` if `authState` was changed by any condition, the `statement` would detect the `status` by `redux/toolkit` official resolution https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk

Comment: Every time, the client side want to access server side API, server side will check the `accessToken` is validated , if not, client side would get error, the frontend program will implement `logout()` function to delete the `isAuth` in `localStorage` and authentication `cookies`.

Comment: I never used `next.js` before, maybe I can try it ! thx a lot