# What's the best approach to map routes in react with user privilege?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

***Question*** :

> the complexity inside the .map function is so high, any suggestions about reorganizing the code to map the routes and apply protection to them at the same time? i tried adding the routes inside an array so I can loop through them, my code is working perfectly but I'm searching for a better approach since this look so complex and wrong

***This is my Routes config file***

```
import Login from '../Pages/Auth/Login';
import Register from '../Pages/Auth/Register';
import Home from '../Pages/Home/Home';

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: <Home />,
    protected: false,
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    component: <Login />,
    protected: false,
  },
  {
    path: '/register',
    component: <Register />,
    protected: false,
  },

];

export default routes;
```

***this is my App.js file***

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { isLoggedIn } from './redux/slices/auth';
import './App.css';
import Layout from './Layouts/Layout';
import routes from './config/routes';

function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(isLoggedIn());
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Layout>
          <Routes>
            {routes.map((route, i) => (
              <>
                {route.path === '/' ? (<Route key={i} exact path={route.path} element={route.component} />) : ((user && route.protected && <Route key={i} path={route.path} element={route.component} />) || (!user && !route.protected && <Route key={i} path={route.path} element={route.component} />))}
              </>
            ))}

          </Routes>
        </Layout>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`react-router-dom` is already very good and the rendering of the routes, and this isn't something you need to reinvent the wheel for. I'd suggest creating a `PrivateRoutes` layout route component (*see this [post](/a/66289280/8690857) for implementation details*) and reconfigure your routes declaration so it can be directly passed to the [`useRoutes`](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.4.0/hooks/use-routes) hook that returns an object to be directly rendered.

Example:

```
import Login from '../Pages/Auth/Login';
import Register from '../Pages/Auth/Register';
import Home from '../Pages/Home/Home';
...
import PrivateRoutes from '../components/PrivateRoutes';

const routesConfig = [
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <Home />,
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    element: <Login />,
  },
  {
    path: '/register',
    element: <Register />,
  },
  {
    element: <PrivateRoutes />, // <-- checks auth status
    children: [
      {
        path: "/dashboard",
        element: <Dashboard />,
      },
      {
        path: "/profile",
        element: <Profile />,
      },
      ... other protected routes ...
    ],
  },
  ... other unprotected routes ...
];

export default routesConfig;
```

...

```
import { useRoutes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { isLoggedIn } from './redux/slices/auth';
import './App.css';
import Layout from './Layouts/Layout';
import routesConfig from './config/routes';

function App() {
  const routes = useRoutes(routesConfig);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(isLoggedIn());
  }, []);

  return (
    <Layout>
      {routes}
    </Layout>
  );
}
```

Wrap `App` with the `BrowserRouter` so the `useRoutes` hook can be used in `App`.

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

...

return (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Comment: that's a great answer but the problem is the children elements are working as routes but the content is not rendered  this is my private route
  if (!user) {
    return (
      <div>404</div>
    );
  }
  return children;
}

Comment: @AliJand You will probably want to re-implement your private route component. Can you clarify what you mean by "content is not rendered"? Can you create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that we could inspect live?

Comment: https://github.com/ichala/short-let-frontend you can check the repo and the branch called  'Update-Routes-Approche' I just updated it right now , what I meant is everything is working great like you said , the only issue is for example the children 
{
        path: "/profile",
        element: <Profile />,
}

the route profile works perfectly but the element is not rendered i get empty page

Comment: @AliJand Ah, I see. The `PrivateRoutes` needs to render an `Outlet` component (*for the nested routes to render their content into*) instead of the `children` prop.

Comment: ahaa , can you provide a link to a example or documentation ?

Comment: okay I got it it should return <Outlet />; instead of children

Comment: @AliJand I did provide a link to an answer of mine that does explain this and provide an example.... but I messed up the link. I've fixed this in my answer. Sorry for any confusion that may've caused. Here it is again: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66289280/8690857