# showing state as null of useLocation hook. want to know why and how can I fix it?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
I am trying to authenticate user and after it only will take to the feed's page and I m using reqres api for login it was working fine now it is not working error Cannot read properties of null (reading 'from') state.form of useLocation please look into it and help me solve this
```

**Below is code please check once.**
I am  trying to expect by giving

```
{
"email": "eve.holt@reqres.in",
"password": "cityslicka"
} 

user will be redirected to feed page
```

authContext code I am trying to authenticate user and after it only will take to the feed's page and I m using reqres api for login it was working fine now it is not working error Cannot read properties of null (reading 'from') state.form of useLocation please look into it and help me solve this  I am trying to authenticate user and after it only will take to the feed's page and I m using reqres api for login it was working fine now it is not working error Cannot read properties of null (reading 'from') state.form of useLocation please look into it and help me solve this  I am trying to authenticate user and after it only will take to the feed's page and I m using reqres api for login it was working fine now it is not working error Cannot read properties of null (reading 'from') state.form of useLocation please look into it and help me solve this

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";


import { useEffect } from "react";    
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";    

export const AuthContext = createContext();    

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {    
  const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState(false);    
  const navigate = useNavigate();    
  const { state } = useLocation();    

  const login = (creds) => {    
    axios    
      .post("https://reqres.in/api/login", creds)    
      .then((d) => {    
        setIsAuth(true);    
        localStorage.setItem("token", d.token);    
        if (state.from) {    
          navigate(state.from, { replace: true });    
        } else {   
          navigate("/");   
        }    
     })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log(e.message);
    setIsAuth(false);
    localStorage.removeItem("token");
  });
  };

  const logout = () => {
setIsAuth(false);
navigate("/");
localStorage.setItem("token", "");
```

};

```
  useEffect(() => {
let token = localStorage.getItem("token");
if (token) {
  setIsAuth(token);
}
  }, []);
  return (
<AuthContext.Provider value={{ isAuth, login, logout }}>
  {children}
</AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: I don't see where any `useLocation` hook is used. Please edit the post to include the relevant code as a properly formatted and readable code snippet instead of as an image. Images are less accessible, can be more difficult to read, and aren't copy/pasteable. See [mcve].

Comment: @DrewReese sir please  check now sorry took  long time to write code in block  I m new to StackOverflow so now code is updated please  check once more

Comment: Where is any `from` state value being passed when issuing a navigation action? I.e. `<Link to="..." state={{ from }}>...</Link>` or `navigate("...", { state: { from } })`? Are you attempting to implement route protection? Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66289280/8690857

Comment: Ok sir got it TY @DrewReese  yes i am implementing route protection