# <Navigate/> in "react-router" directly redirects from login page to home page without signing in at sign in page in localhost

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-dom

I am creating a LinkedIn clone where I am adding firebase authentication on the sign-in page. I have added `{props.user && <Navigate to="/home" />}` where the `user` contains user information while signing in like name, email, etc.

But due to some reason, when I run `yarn start`, the sign-in page opens for a fraction of a second and then is redirected to the home page, which goes blank (only we can see the content after refreshing once)

My Login.js:

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { signInAPI } from "../actions";
import { Navigate } from "react-router";

const Login = (props) => {
  return (
    <Container>
      {props.user && <Navigate to="/home" />}
      <Nav>
        //other stuff
      </Nav>
      <Section>
        //other stuff
      </Section>
    </Container>
  );
};

//styling code

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    user: state.userState.user,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  signIn: () => dispatch(signInAPI()),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

App.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Login from "./components/Login";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import { getUserAuth } from "./actions";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

function App(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    props.getUserAuth();
  }, []); 

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Login />}></Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/Home" element={<Home />}></Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

const mapStateToPorps = (state) => {
  return {};
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  getUserAuth: () => dispatch(getUserAuth()),
});

export default connect(mapStateToPorps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Yet to complete the whole project so `useEffect` is not final, still it works

Thought of using `<Redirect />` but it doesn't work for newer versions, not even when I reinstalled `node_modules`, `react-router-dom`, `react-router`, it gives this `error export 'Redirect' (imported as 'Redirect') was not found in 'react-router'`

Comment: Don't use 2 routers. Where is any `Redirect` component imported and referenced? `Redirect` is a RRDv5 component, it was effectively replaced by the `Navigate` component from RRDv6.

Comment: @DrewReese I tried `<Redirect />` but it gives an error directly, `<Navigate />` works for newer versions so I posted for this.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use 2 routers. The router rendering `Login` is navigating to a route it doesn't know about so nothing will be matched and render until you reload the page and the other router can read the URL path.

Move all the routes into a single router.

```
function App(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    props.getUserAuth();
  }, []); 

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Login />} />
          <Route path="/Home" element={<Home />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`react-router-dom@6` doesn't export a `Redirect` component, it was replaced by the `Navigate` component that serves a similar function. If you want to replicate redirection then you should also pass the `replace` prop.

```
const Login = (props) => {
  return (
    <Container>
      {props.user && <Navigate to="/home" replace />}
      <Nav>
        //other stuff
      </Nav>
      <Section>
        //other stuff
      </Section>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

If you would like a more conventional route protection implementation then I recommend reviewing this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66289280/8690857) regarding implementing protected routes. It decouples route protection from the actual routed content you want to display. It's separation of concerns.