# How to popup login screen(Azure AD) without using a button when accessing URL(local host in my case) directly?

Tags: reactjs, azure, authentication, react-router, azure-active-directory

I have created a basic application of react in which I have implemented the concept of routing and for authentication I have used Azure AD. Its working fine when I try to login using the login button but I want that when I try to access the home page it automatically redirects to the login page(Microsoft login) without clicking any button.

This is my code for "App.js" and in "AuthConfig" I have simply declared my clientId, redirecturi, scopes and authority.

```
import Prices from "./pages/Prices";
import Ticket from "./pages/Ticket";
import Money from "./pages/Money";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import {config} from "./AuthConfig";
import {PublicClientApplication} from '@azure/msal-browser';
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component<any, any>{
  publicClientApplication: PublicClientApplication;  
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isAuthenticated: false,
      user:{}
    };
    this.login=this.login.bind(this)
    
    this.publicClientApplication = new PublicClientApplication({
      auth:{
        clientId: config.appId,
        redirectUri: config.redirectUri,
        authority: config.authority
      },
      cache:{
        cacheLocation: "sessionStorage",
        storeAuthStateInCookie: false
      }
    });
  }
  async login(){
    try{
      
      await this.publicClientApplication.loginPopup(
        {
        scopes: config.scopes,
        prompt:"select_account"
      });
      this.setState({isAuthenticated:true})
  }
  catch(err){
    this.setState({
      isAuthenticated:false,
      user:{},
      error:err
    });
  }
}
logout(){
  this.publicClientApplication.logoutPopup();
}

render() {
  return(
    <div className="App">
     
      {this.state.isAuthenticated ? <p>
        <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Prices />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
      </p>: 
      <p>
        <button onClick={() => this.login()} > Login </button>
      </p>
      }
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>         
          <Route path="/Money" element={<Money />}></Route>
          <Route path="/Ticket" element={<Ticket/>}></Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
      
     
    </div>
  );
}
}
export default App;
```

Comment: You know that popups that open on websites without any user interaction are usually spam? Popup blockers in browsers typically block these. You might need to use loginRedirect instead as you can do redirects without interaction.

Comment: Does this help answer your question for a general "how do I redirect for authentication using react-router-don"? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66289280/8690857

Comment: @DrewReese No its not working in my case

Comment: No, *what* is not working in your case? Can you be more specific?

Comment: @DrewReese I have created a UI for login using Azure AD and the login page is opening when I click on login button, but I want to open the login page automatically when my localhost gets fired.

Comment: If the login UI is rendered based on clicking a button, is there a reason you can't just trigger that login UI programmatically (*i.e. when a component mounts*) instead of as an asynchronous UI event (*i.e. in response to a button being clicked*)? You just want that `login` function to be called without user interaction? What is the condition you want this to happen?

Comment: @DrewReese So my point is, when I run my react application using "yarn start" it opens a page with that login button and when we click on that login button it opens the login screen which is done using Azure AD in my case. But I want to open the Azure AD login screen directly when I run "yarn start" command.

Comment: Right, I think I get that part. Why can't your app code just directly open the login screen instead of waiting for a button to be pressed?

Comment: @DrewReese I have tried the same but its not working properly as the routing is getting called everytime and the page gets logout by itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want the `login` function to be called automatically when the `App` component mounts instead of when the button is clicked you can do this in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method.

Example:

```
class App extends React.Component<any, any> {
  publicClientApplication: PublicClientApplication;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isAuthenticated: false,
      user: {}
    };

    this.publicClientApplication = new PublicClientApplication({
      auth: {
        clientId: config.appId,
        redirectUri: config.redirectUri,
        authority: config.authority
      },
      cache: {
        cacheLocation: "sessionStorage",
        storeAuthStateInCookie: false
      }
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.login();
  }

  login = sync () => {
    try {
      await this.publicClientApplication.loginPopup({
        scopes: config.scopes,
        prompt: "select_account"
      });
      this.setState({ isAuthenticated: true });
    } catch(err) {
      this.setState({
        isAuthenticated: false,
        user: {},
        error: err
      });
    }
  }

  logout() {
    this.publicClientApplication.logoutPopup();
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.isAuthenticated && (
          <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<Prices />} />
            </Routes>
          </BrowserRouter>
        )}
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/Money" element={<Money />} />
            <Route path="/Ticket" element={<Ticket />} />
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm also not sure what is going on with usage of two routers, you'll very likely want to merge these so all routes are rendered within the same single routing context.

Example:

```
<div className="App">
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route
        path="/"
        element={this.state.isAuthenticated ? <Prices /> : null}
      />
      <Route path="/Money" element={<Money />} />
      <Route path="/Ticket" element={<Ticket />} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `componentDidMount` in React components and `useEffect` in functional components won't work because login and `acquireToken` APIs are async. You need to ensure that the resulting promises have resolved before invoking another one. [This page](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-react/docs/errors.md#interaction_in_progress) explains it well and how to solve the issue