# why Navigate component wont redirect to home page after login?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar"
import Home from "./routes/Home"
import Signup from "./routes/Signup"
import Login from "./routes/Login"
import useAuthContext from "./hooks/useAuthContext"
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom"
export default function App() {
  const { user } = useAuthContext()
  const router = createBrowserRouter(
    createRoutesFromElements(
      <Route path="/" element={<Navbar />}>
        <Route index element={!user ? <Navigate to="/login" /> : <Home />} />
        <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      </Route>
    )
  )
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />
}
```

First it shows the login page, after I login it will stay on login page. how do I fix this?

I did try many things. it wont worked, i know in v5 I can use redirect component to redirect page.

Comment: It should work. Are you sure that `user` is not `undefined` or `null`?

Comment: I tried to print out the user. first, it displayed null then after I logged in, I got the user info object.

Comment: There is nothing in this code that would cause it to leave the current `/login` location and got to `/`.  You need a `<Navigate to="/">` somewhere in the `<Login/>` element.

Comment: Where does any component navigate ***from*** the `"/login"` route? Is there a `Navigate` component navigating to `"/"` in the app? You may need to [edit] the post to include a more complete [mcve].

Comment: Does this answer help explain the process of redirecting after successful authentication? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66289280/8690857

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have code that redirects from `/` to `/login` when the user is logged out:

```
<Route index element={!user ? <Navigate to="/login" /> : <Home />} />
```

You **don't** have code that redirects from `/login` to `/` when the user is logged in.

You need to add a `<Navigate>` in your `/login` route, either at the top level or inside of your `Login` component.

This is the simplest solution:

```
<Route path="/login" element={user ? <Navigate to="/"> : <Login />} />
```

(note: `Navigate` is the v6 equivalent of `Redirect`)