# Changing React navbar component with redux data

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux, react-router

So basically here I want my navbar routes to change along with login info from the redux reducer, but the routes stay static.

```
useEffect(() => {
  getUserInfo();
  console.log(props.userInfo?. isLoggedIn)
  if (props?.userInfo?.isLoggedIn == true) {
    setUserState(['profile','dashboard','wallet']);
  } else {
    setUserState(['sign-in','sign-in','sign-in']);
  }
},[props])
```

So here I store my routes in the `useState` hook as an array, but this `useEffect` hook does not cast until I change the route by a `<Link></Link>` component.
I want it to cast as soon as the redux state changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
const [userState, setUserState] = useState([])
useEffect(() => {
    getUserInfo();
    console.log(props.userInfo?. isLoggedIn)
    if(props?.userInfo?.isLoggedIn == true) {
      setUserState(['profile','dashboard','wallet']);
    } else {
      setUserState(['sign-in','sign-in','sign-in']);
    }
  },[props,userState])
```

Add userState in useEffect dependancy array.

Comment: Adding `userState` as a dependency would create a render loop since the hook callback enqueues a `userState` update.

Answer (score 0):

Don't store derived state in React state, this is a React anti-pattern. You can simply rendered the UI from the "dependencies" directly. This assumes the component is correctly subscribed to the Redux store and `userInfo` is selected state from the store.

```
const authenticatedRoutes = ['profile','dashboard','wallet'];
const anonymousRoutes = ['sign-in','sign-in','sign-in'];
...

return (
  ...
  {(props.userInfo?.isLoggedIn ? authenticatedRoutes : anonymousRoutes).map(path => {
    // compute and return JSX
  })}
  ...
);
```

A more common/practical solution is to create route protector components that read the `userInfo.isLoggedIn` property and conditionally render the protected route/component or redirect to a "safe route". You can read more about general route protection in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66289280/8690857).