# React-router v6 breadcrumbs and partially matching routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, breadcrumbs

I am working with react-router-dom v6.8.1 (newest version as of now), and previously had a working breadcrumb setup using this third-party lib called  [use-react-router-breadcrumbs](https://github.com/icd2k3/use-react-router-breadcrumbs), but according to it's doc, they are now instead recommending doing it the "built-in react-router way", that [is documented here](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-matches#breadcrumbs). It's based on attaching a crumb to the handle object of each route, and retrieve it using the `useMatches` hook.

So I rewrote the code, but it has a quite major flaw that I cannot get around. Say that I have 3 routes, where 2 and 3 is nested below 1:

```
{
    path: '/',
    element: <Layout />,
    handle: {
      crumb: () => 'Home',
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: '/users',
        element: <UserList />,
        handle: {
          crumb: () => 'Users',
        },
      },
      {
        path: '/users/:id',
        element: <UserDetails />,
        handle: {
          crumb: () => <DynamicUserNameCrumb />,
        },
      },
   ]
}
```

With the custom lib you can go to `/users/:id` and get a breadcrumb for each one of these routes, making the entire breadcrumbs look like:

"Home -> Users -> John Doe"

However, when using the new built-in way with the `useMatches()` hook, I only get a match on route 1 and 3. Route 2 (/users) is not considered a match, and I cannot access the crumb for that route. Result is this, which is not what I want:

"Home -> John Doe"

So my question is: How are you supposed to handle this kind of situation? Nesting route 3 under 2 was my first idea, and this made the crumbs correct, but then it actually renders the component defined for route 2 (User list), and I only want it to render route 1 (layout) and 3 (User details page).

I was hoping that maybe `useMatches()` would be able to accept configuration for also returning partial matches, but it seems that this hook does not accept any input.

I am close to reverting and going back to the third party lib, but wanted to ask here before I do so, since they explicitly recommended using the native solution based on `useMatches` and a `handle` object. I figured there *must* be a solution for this if this is the officially recommended way to handle breadcrumbs in react-router

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can tell it is because `"/users"` and `"/users/:id"` are sibling routes. Refactor the routes config such that `"/users/:id"` is a child route of `"/users"` so there's a "logical path" and individual segments from `"/"` to `"users"` to `":id"`.

Example:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Layout />,
    handle: {
      crumb: () => "Home"
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: "/users",
        handle: {
          crumb: () => "Users"
        },
        children: [
          {
            index: true,
            element: <UserList />
          },
          {
            path: "/users/:id",
            element: <UserDetails />,
            handle: {
              crumb: () => <DynamicUserNameCrumb />
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]);
```

[image: Edit react-router-v6-breadcrumbs-and-partially-matching-routes]

[image]

Comment: Yes! It seems I was not aware of the pattern where you define the parent without an element, and then use the "index:true" on the child to make the rendering correct. This works, so I'm going with this solution! Thanks a alot!

Comment: @KnutMarius Yes, well, that was done so that the `UserList` could still be a "sibling" route and not need to render an `Outlet` for a nested route rendering `UserDetails`. Routes without an `element` prop implicitly render an `Outlet` component. Glad this works for you. Cheers and good luck!

Comment: In these situations it's not an outlet/layout kind of situation between user list and user details. I always just want to render _one_ of them at the time. I was not sure if this was a kind of scenario where it was intended to use nested routes. I am quite sure I've seen examples from the past where this situation is treated with a flat route structure, and only the specificity of the paths decide which route to render. Do you know if the nested routes is considered best practice way currently?

Comment: @KnutMarius Route nesting certainly makes *some* things easier, but I wouldn't go as far as to say it's a "best practice". Flat lists of all routes are still valid. The nested routes might just be a path towards making the code a little more DRY.

Comment: Not that it's directly related, but I'm also working on a way to authorize different routes, and doing the nested way could perhaps also help. I could then create a `<Protected/>` layout which takes the required permissions and put that on the parent route (in this case /users). Then it would automatically protect all the child routes as well...

Comment: @KnutMarius That's absolutely correct. I have an answer with route protection examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66289280/8690857.