# Protect a SPA application in React with a login - why does this methodology not work?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am learning ReactJS so I am completely new at this.

I created an authentication/authorization service that I know works in React just fine. What I am trying to do is protect the primary application with a login. As I understand, I want a high-order component such as this in order to protect the core of the application:

```
const withAuth = (Component) => {
  const AuthenticatedComponent = () => {
    const isAuthenticated = MyService.isUserAuthenticated();
    if (!isAuthenticated) {
      return <Navigate to="/login" />;
    }
    return <Component />;
  };

  return AuthenticatedComponent;
};

export default withAuth;
```

I have two components that are pretty simple to test the theory that are both very similar. Essentially they look like this:

```
export default function DefaultLandingPage() {
  return(
    <>
    <div>
      This would be the dashboard page after login.
    </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

```
export default function LoginPage() {
  return(
    <>
    <div>
      This is where the user would log in.
    </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

I tried to use these in my `App.js` file.

First I tried this:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" exact component={withAuth(DefaultLandingPage) } />
      <Route path="/login" element={ <LoginPage /> } />
    </Routes>
    </>
  );
}
```

That results in:

> Matched leaf route at location "/" does not have an element or Component. This means it will render an  with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page.

I tried changing it to:

```
<Route path="/" exact element={ withAuth(DefaultLandingPage) } />
```

Which results in:

> Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

Can someone point me in the proper direction?

I did find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66289122/how-to-create-a-protected-route-with-react-router-dom) and am headed down that route right now; however, I am not sure what my incorrect logic is here.

Can someone explain why my logic doesn't work here?

What concerns me, is that I want to also protect the pages with fine-grained privileges and was hoping to create something that would function like this:

```
<Route path="/" exact element={ withAuth(DefaultLandingPage) } />
<Route path="/some-sub-area" element={ withAuth(withPermission(SomeSubArea, 'permission-xyz')) } />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first case, make sure your prop `component` is capitalized to `Component` per the router documentation. For your second issue, your `withAuth` function returns a function reference to `AuthenticatedComponent` rather than treating it as a functional component. Opting to return `<AuthenticatedComponent/>` should send you in the right direction!

Comment: Those two things make sense. Is the preferred configuration as of v6 or should I head full throttle down the v6 route listed on that other post?

Comment: The v6 route listed on the post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/70954599/12109958) is the most standard configuration for private/protected routes -- although if you just remove your `withAuth` wrapper, and render the components children (i.e.`<AuthenticatedComponent><DefaultLandingPage/></AuthenticatedComponent>`) in `AuthenticatedComponent` you're already there : )

Comment: I'll head down that route. I have just a blank app isolated to learn nothing but this, so it's not like I'm throwing away a ton of work.

Comment: Nice, good luck!

Comment: FYI - got it working. Now to figure out how to protect it as a SPA.

Answer (score 0):

The `react-router-dom` `Route` component hasn't any `component`, so this is the cause of the first error regarding a missing `element`.

The `Route` component's `element` prop takes ***only*** a `React.ReactNode`, e.g. it takes a JSX literal. `withAuth(DefaultLandingPage)` isn't valid JSX.

You've a couple options:

1. Export a decorated version of the `DefaultLandingPage` component, to be rendered as JSX.

   ```
   const DefaultLandingPage = () => {
     ...
   };

   export default withAuth(DefaultLandingPage);
   ```

   ```
   function App() {
     return (
       <Routes>
         <Route path="/" element={<DefaultLandingPage /> } />
         <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
       </Routes>
     );
   }
   ```
2. Implement protected routes in a more conventional method, as per the Stackoverflow answer you linked. Using Higher Order Components for authentication as a little old these days.

   ```
   const AuthenticatedComponent = () => {
     const isAuthenticated = MyService.isUserAuthenticated();

     return isAuthenticated
       ? <Outlet />
       : <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
   };
   ```

   ```
   function App() {
     return (
       <Routes>
         <Route element={<AuthenticatedComponent />}>
           <Route path="/" element={<DefaultLandingPage /> } />
         </Route>
         <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
       </Routes>
     );
   }
   ```

If the eventual goal is to also use role-based route protection then you'd implement something similar to the following:

```
const PermissionRoute = ({ permissions = [] }) => {
  const permission = /* wherever you get current user's permission */

  return !permissions.length || permissions.includes(permission) ? (
    <Outlet />
  ) : (
    <Navigate to="/login" replace /> // <-- or any safe non-permission route
  );
};
```

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      ...
      <Route element={<PermissionRoute permissions={["...", ...]} />}>
        ...
      </Route>
      ...
    </Routes>
  );
}
```