# Access restriction in _app.js with frebase and redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js

I have an application where people can access to the website if not login, however they should be able to access to `"/app"`, `"/app/*"` only if authenticated. My code below works but for some reason there is half a second, or a second of the content of `"/app"` shown before showing the message `"you're not allowed to..."`. Any idea why is that?

```
import { Provider, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import '../styles/front.css';
import '../styles/app.css';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { wrapper, store } from '../store';
import { login, logout, selectUser } from "../redux/slices/userSlice";
import { auth } from '../firebase';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const user = useSelector(selectUser);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const router = useRouter();
  const isAppPage = router.pathname.startsWith('/app');
  const [shouldRender, setShouldRender] = useState(true); // New state variable
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((userAuth) => {
      if (userAuth) {
        dispatch(login({
          email: userAuth.email,
          uid: userAuth.uid,
          displayName: userAuth.displayName,
          photoUrl: userAuth.photoURL
        }));
        setIsAuthenticated(true);
      } else {
        if (isAppPage) {
          setShouldRender(false);
        }
        dispatch(logout());
        setIsAuthenticated(false);
      }
      setLoading(false); // Set loading to false once the authentication status is checked
    });

    return () => unsubscribe(); // Cleanup the event listener when the component unmounts
  }, []);

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      {shouldRender ? <Component {...pageProps} /> : <p>You're not allowed to access that page.</p>}
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default wrapper.withRedux(MyApp);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically need a condition with a third value that is neither "show the content" nor "you can't see this content". Something like a "pending" state that conditionally renders neither the `Component` nor the `"You're not allowed to access that page."` text.

The initial `shouldRender` state matches one of these two states you don't want to immediately render. Start with `undefined` and explicitly check for this and conditionally return null or a loading indicator, etc.
Example:

```js
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const user = useSelector(selectUser);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const router = useRouter();
  const isAppPage = router.pathname.startsWith('/app');

  const [shouldRender, setShouldRender] = useState(); // initially undefined

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((userAuth) => {
      if (userAuth) {
        dispatch(login({
          email: userAuth.email,
          uid: userAuth.uid,
          displayName: userAuth.displayName,
          photoUrl: userAuth.photoURL
        }));
        setIsAuthenticated(true);
        setShouldRender(true); // <-- show the content
      } else {
        if (isAppPage) {
          setShouldRender(false); // <-- hide content
        }
        dispatch(logout());
        setIsAuthenticated(false);
      }
      setLoading(false);
    });

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  if (shouldRender === undefined) {
    return null; // or loading indicator/spinner/etc
  }

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      {shouldRender
        ? <Component {...pageProps} />
        : <p>You're not allowed to access that page.</p>
      }
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, if not logout i cannot see the content of the website anymore, if i go to /app correct behaviour showing im not allowed

Comment: because users still need to be able to access the website, only if login they can access to /app/etc however

Comment: @BrianMillot Are these routes you are rendering somewhere in your app? If so then you likely need to implement [protected routes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66289280/8690857) instead of conditionally rendering all or nothing here in the root app component. Same idea as this answer, but applied at the routing level. Does this make sense?

Comment: Thanks mate, nope but just by doing if (isAppPage) {
          setShouldRender(false); // <-- hide content
        } else {   setShouldRender(true); } seems to have fixed the issue for now thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That is because `shouldRender` is true on first load, and after that it goes inside useEffect and get auth state inside onAuthStateChanged.

you should set it to false here:

```
const [shouldRender, setShouldRender] = useState(false); // New state variable
```

and update inside it:

```
 if (userAuth) {
    dispatch(login({
      email: userAuth.email,
      uid: userAuth.uid,
      displayName: userAuth.displayName,
      photoUrl: userAuth.photoURL
    }));
    setShouldRender(true);
    setIsAuthenticated(true);
  }
```

**Update**:
You can use another state to check loaded state.
so use:

```
const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);    
const [shouldRender, setShouldRender] = useState(false);
```

and update inside useEffect:

```
  if (userAuth) {
    dispatch(login({
      email: userAuth.email,
      uid: userAuth.uid,
      displayName: userAuth.displayName,
      photoUrl: userAuth.photoURL
    }));
    setLoaded(true);
    setShouldRender(true);
    setIsAuthenticated(true);
  }
```

For render use this:

```
 return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      {!loaded? <LoaderComponent />: shouldRender
        ? <Component {...pageProps} />
        : <p>You're not allowed to access that page.</p>
      }
    </Provider>
  );
```

Comment: This just inverts the problem. Instead of unauthenticated users seeing protected content prior to the "You're not allowed..." text, authenticated users will see the "You're not allowed..." text for a brief moment before seeing the protected content.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I hope it makes sense now.