# PrivateRoute in react-router-dom:6.8.0

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm build custom PrivateRoute for chat app. Here me **PrivateRoute**:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Route, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

interface PrivateRouteProps {
  element: React.ComponentType<any>;
  path: string;
}

export function PrivateRoute({ element: Element, path }: PrivateRouteProps) {
  const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get('http://golang:8080')
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          setAuthenticated(true);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <Route
      path={path}
      element={
        authenticated ? <Element /> : <Navigate to="/login" replace={true} />
      }
    />
  );
}
```

How I use it: `<PrivateRoute path={RouterPath.ROOT} element={Main} />`

Picture of my code: [image: My code]

When I build my project in console I have these errors: [Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8WSE.png) So how to use custom PrivateRoute?

Comment: You do it the other way around

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66289122/how-to-create-a-protected-route-with-react-router-dom

Comment: Thanks, but this answers didn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can change your private route component, it will only decide to render children or not, no props

```
import { PropsWithChildren } from 'react'

export function PrivateRoute({ children }: PropsWithChildren) {
 const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(false);
 useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get('http://golang:8080')
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          setAuthenticated(true);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, []);

  return <>
     authenticated ? (
        children
     ) : (
        <Navigate to="/login" replace={true} />
     )
    </>
}
```

Then use it that way

```
<Route path={path}>
  <Route path={RouterPath.ROOT} element={<PrivateRoute><Main/></PrivateRoute>}/>        
</Route>
```

Comment: Thanks, Its work perfectly, but <PrivateRoute> underlined red line and says: `PrivateRoute cannot be used as a JSX component. Its return type 'string | number | boolean | ReactFragment | Element | null | undefined' is not a valid JSX element. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type ''Element | null.`

Comment: You can wrap it in a reactFragment, let me change the answer and show you how

Comment: Can you check now, it should fix the typing problem

Comment: `authenticated` is initially false, so the redirect will ***always*** be rendered ***before*** the `useEffect` can run and check if the user is authenticated and update the `authenticated` state. This implementation is flawed.

Comment: The answer was about router not about the whole implementation