# Redirect non-authenticated users, AWS Amplify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, aws-amplify

I am trying to build a web app with AWS Amplify. I have authentication configured, but I want certain pages to be for authenticated users only e.g. anyone can see the home page, but only logged in users should see `"/dashboard"`. I am currently using AWS Amplify as my backend and a React front-end, using `react-router` v6 to route between pages.

Currently, my routing code is very naive (it is my first time using React), and is in App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Route,
  Routes,
} from 'react-router-dom';

import Login from './pages/Login';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import Dashboard from './pages/Dashboard';
import ErrorPage from './pages/ErrorPage';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<ErrorPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I first tried wrapping the page I want gated with `withAuthenticator`, but this just caused a loop of seeing the login box.

```
function Dashboard({ signOut, user }) {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hello {user.username}, this is still in development.</h1>
      <button onClick={signOut}> Sign out</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default withAuthenticator(Dashboard);
```

I have also tried to add a function to check if the user is authenticated, and return different bodies, but this just shows a white screen for both an authenticated and non-authenticated users. I believe it is because it is `async`, but I am not familiar enough with react to understand why or how to fix it.

```
async function isAuthed() {
  try {
    await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
    return true;
  } catch(e) {
    return false;
  }
}

async function Dashboard() {
  if (await isAuthed()) {
    return (
      <>
        <h1>Hello, this is still in development.</h1>
      </>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <>
        <h1>Please login to view this page.</h1>
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

I have also tried to see if there is some method of asynchronous routing, but not sure how I would implement that.

Edit:

@Jlove's solution has worked as intended, my updated `App.js` routing code is now:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Route,
  Routes,
  useNavigate,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import { Amplify, Auth } from 'aws-amplify'

import Login from './pages/Login';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import Dashboard from './pages/Dashboard';
import ErrorPage from './pages/ErrorPage';
import Unauthenticated from './pages/Unauthenticated';

function RequireAuth({ children }) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
      .then(() => setIsAuth(true))
      .catch(() => {
        navigate("/unauthenticated")
      })
  }, [])
    
  return isAuth && children;
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route
          path="/dashboard" 
          element={
            <RequireAuth>
              <Dashboard />
            </RequireAuth>
          }
        />
        <Route path="*" element={<ErrorPage />} />
        <Route path="/unauthenticated" element={<Unauthenticated />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: For general route protection my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66289280/8690857) may be helpful, but can you [edit] the post to include relevant route protection code you are using? See [mcve].

Comment: Your comment is the first I have actually read about route protection in use - I think that my naivity and inexperience didn't help me trying to find the correct search terms. 

I will update my original question with both my original routing code, as well as the updated version based on the solution below by @Jlove that has worked for me.

Comment: When `Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()` resolves, does that ***always*** mean the user is successfully authenticated, or can it resolve and basically say the user check failed and the current user is not authenticated?

Comment: That is correct, `Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()` will return a user object for the user currently authenticated, if there is no currently authenticated user, then it will return an error ([source](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/manageusers/q/platform/js/#retrieve-current-authenticated-user)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to go about this by wrapping your component route in an authorization component:

```
<Route 
    path="/somePathToProtect"
    element={
        <RequireAuth>
            <Dashboard />
        </RequireAuth>
    }
/>

export function RequireAuth({children}) {
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
            .then(
                () => setIsAuth(true)
            )
            .catch(() => {
                navigate('/routeToCatchNonAuth')
            })
    }, [])

    return isAuth && children;
}
```

The goal here is to gatekeep your route based on what `Auth` returns. If `Auth` takes the catch route, utilize the router to navigate the user to wherever you want unauthorized users to go.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to keep separate the logic of protecting routes from the content each route renders. Don't mix in authentication with the UI/content components you want to render on routes.

A common protection pattern is to use a [layout route](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#layout-routes) to wrap an entire group of routes you want to protect access to. You will create a layout route component that triggers an effect to check the current user's authentication status, and conditionally return:

- Nothing/loading (*if status isn't known yet*)
- An `Outlet` for the protected content (*if user is authenticated*),
- Aa redirect to a non-protected route (*if user is unauthenticated*).

The prevents (a) accidental access to protected pages prior to knowing a user is unauthenticated and (b) accidental redirects to login prior to knowing a user was really already authenticated.

Example:

```js
const checkAuthentication = async () => {
  try {
    await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
    return true;
  } catch {
    return false;
  }
};
```

```
import { Outlet, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const ProtectedRoute = () => {
  const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState(undefined);

  useEffect(() => {
    checkAuthentication()
      .then(() => setIsAuth(true))
      .catch(() => setIsAuth(false));
  }, []);

  if (isAuth === undefined) {
    return null; // or loading spinner/indicator/etc
  }
    
  return isAuth ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
}
```

Wrap the routes that need to be auth-protected.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Route,
  Routes,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from './pages/Login';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import Dashboard from './pages/Dashboard';
import ErrorPage from './pages/ErrorPage';
import ProtectedRoute from './components/ProtectedRoute';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route element={<ProtectedRoute />}>
          <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
          {/* ... other protected routes ... */}
        </Route>
        <Route path="*" element={<ErrorPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response and explanation Drew, that makes a lot of sense, and I really like the ease of extensibility. When `ProtectedRoute` is evaluating `isAuth`, if it is undefined, when it resolves, I'm assuming it will re-route to the corresponding path, but I'm not too sure how/why.

Comment: @supinie It's *technically* already on the route, but the parent layout route is applying some conditional rendering for the current condition. When the `isAuth` resolves and the user is authenticated, the `Outlet` is rendered which allows the *already matched* route to then actually output its content to the DOM.

Comment: Ahhh, okay that makes lots of sense to think about it that way, thanks!