# How to create react-admin custom route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-admin

I tried to create a custom route in my react-admin app, but I get an error when I try to load it.

Here is the code:

```
// src/pages/MyAdmin.tsx
export const MyAdmin = () => (
  <Admin
    dataProvider={dataProvider}
  >
    <Resource name="users" list={UserList} />
    <CustomRoutes>
      <Route path="/reg" element={<Registration />} />
    </CustomRoutes>
  </Admin>
);
```

When I go to /#/reg I just get a "Something went wrong. A client error occurred and your request couldn't be completed". And the console outputs an error saying: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')"

I was just trying to follow this https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Routing.html but I don't know what I did wrong.

Thank you for your help.

I already tried to move my custom "MyAdmin" component to the App component itself but to no avail.

Comment: `Route` should be wrapped in a `Routes` component. Other than this, we need more context. Can you [edit] to provide a more complete [mcve]? My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66289280/8690857) might help clarify general route protection implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the error is inside the registration component. The error is being caught by the React Error Boundary, but the routing itself is correct.

As in the documentation: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Layout.html#error

> React-admin uses React’s Error Boundaries to render this page when any
> component **in the page** throws an unrecoverable error

So check the code inside the registration component or try with an empty one.

Also check that you are importing the Route component from react-router-dom and not from other library.