# Efficiently granting user access based on authorization levels and implementing route protection

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

Here is the protected route where I have checked for `isAuthenticated`. The `isAuthenticated` status is managed by Redux. When there is no token saved in local storage, `isAuthenticated` is set to false. This is for protective routes:

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { RootState } from "src/store";

const ProtectedRoute = ({ children }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { isAuthenticated } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.login);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isAuthenticated) {
      navigate("/");
    }
  }, [isAuthenticated]);
  return children;
};

ProtectedRoute.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

Logic to check user permission:

```
import { ReactNode, Fragment } from "react";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useUserRoles } from "src/utils/ToastMessage";

interface RolesAuthRouteProps {
  children: ReactNode;
  roles: Array<string>;
}

export function RolesAuthRoute({ children, roles }: RolesAuthRouteProps) {
  const userRoles = useUserRoles();

  const canAccess = userRoles.some(userRole => roles.includes(userRole));

  if (canAccess) return <>{children}</>;

  return <Navigate to="/" />;
}
```

Logic to check unprotected route:

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

import { RootState } from "src/store";

const UnProtectedRoute = () => {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.login);
  return isAuthenticated ? <Navigate to="/dashboard" replace /> : <Outlet />;
};

export default UnProtectedRoute;
```

Here I have defined all routes:

```
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route element={<UnProtectedRoute />}>
        <Route element={<Login />} path="/" />
      </Route>

      <Route
        path="dashboard"
        element={
          <ProtectedRoute>
            <RolesAuthRoute roles={["admin"]}>
              <Dashboard />
            </RolesAuthRoute>
          </ProtectedRoute>
        }
      />
      <Route
        path="reports"
        element={
          <ProtectedRoute>
            <RolesAuthRoute roles={["admin"]}>
              <DashboardDetails />
            </RolesAuthRoute>
          </ProtectedRoute>
        }
      />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

**ToastMessage.tsx**

```
export type UserRole = "admin" | "root" | "user";

export function useUserRoles() {
  // some logic or api call to get the roles
  // for demonstration purposes it's just hard coded
  const userRoles: UserRole[] = ["admin", "root"];

  // return the current user roles
  return userRoles;
}
```

When I attempt to navigate to reports, only dashboard links are rendered. I am unable to access other protected routes.

Comment: Is this `import { useUserRoles } from "src/utils/ToastMessage";` import correct? Does this help answer your question about protected routes implementation? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66289122/how-to-create-a-protected-route-with-react-router-dom Can you [edit] to clarify what links you are referring to? See [mcve].

Comment: After adding links to the items in the dashboard menu list, it began functioning perfectly

Answer (score -1):

I've used this method and works:

create a function to export your authenticated routes in my case is called AppRoutes and another function to export the unauthenticated routes in case is called AuthRoutes.

[image]

In your App.tsx

```
return (

    <NavigationContainer>
      <Routes />
    </NavigationContainer>
)
```

I hope this may help you.