# Why is my code rendering a blank page when using React router Outlet to protect route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to use 'Outlet' with React Router and I must be missing something basic.

I am 'wrapping' my 'HomePage' in a my PrivateRoute.  If the user if not logged in, it redirects the to my login page. However if they are logged in, then I'm just getting a blank page in the browser. There are no errors in the console and the HTML body rendered is just the following.

```
<body>
    <div id="root"><div class="App"></div></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
</body>
```

I was expecting to see the contents of Homepage

HomePage.jsx

```
import React from 'react'

const HomePage = () => {
  return (
    <div>HomePage</div>
  )
}

export default HomePage
```

App.jsx

```
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import { AuthProvider } from "./context/AuthContext";
import HomePage from "./pages/HomePage";
import LoginPage from "./pages/LoginPage";
import PrivateRoutes from "./utils/PrivateRoute";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <AuthProvider>
          <Routes>
             <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
             <Route element={<PrivateRoutes/>}>  
                <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />}/>
             </Route>
          </Routes>
        </AuthProvider>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

PrivateRoutes.jsx

```
import { Outlet, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useContext } from 'react'
import AuthContext from '../context/AuthContext'


const PrivateRoutes = () => {
    let { user } = useContext(AuthContext)
     
    return user ? <Outlet/> : <Navigate to="/login"/>
}

export default PrivateRoutes
```

Comment: I don't see any overt issue with the routing and `HomePage` code. Check the exports/imports of components as it looks like there may've been an issue exporting a component and causing the Router to not render anything. Think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: I can give it a go. I don't think it's an export or import issue? I only get this issue when trying to use 'Outlet' if I just do a 'return !user : <Navigate to='login'/>: children'  and wrap the homepage route in the protected route it works fine? The private routes code was taken from here 'https://github.com/divanov11/React-Auth-Private-Routes-With-Appwrite/blob/master/2-final/src/App.jsx'

Comment: Here's a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/why-is-my-code-rendering-a-blank-page-when-using-react-router-outlet-to-protect-cwfy27) I just stood up, copy/pasted your code, and it's working as expected. Feel free to fork it and see if you can reproduce the issue that we could then check out.

Comment: ok thank you very much, I'll see if I can reproduce. It's rather frustrating because I don't seem to have anyway to troubleshoot this.

Comment: You can compare your `PrivateRoutes` implementation and usage against [How to create a protected route with react-router-dom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66289280/8690857) to see what may be an issue in your code. Like I said though, I didn't see any issue with what you shared here. You can test the home route with something simple like `<Route path="/" element={<h1>HomePage</h1>} />` to see if the plain text is rendered.

Comment: I worked out the issue. I was importing the wrong PrivateRoute file. 'import PrivateRoutes from "./utils/PrivateRoute";' Note how it's singular not plural. So I was loading the wrong file. Thank you for your help and sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: I see. Glad you got it sorted out. I'm voting to close as "not reproducible or was caused by typo". Cheers and good luck!