# React-Redux no route is found

Tags: javascript, react-redux, firebase-authentication, react-router-dom

I'm facing a problem with my code. I'm using `react-redux` and firebase. I'm on the path: `"/profile"` after I have already logged in. When I'm clicking on the log out button, I'm supposed to be sent off to the login page, but actually the UI does sign me off but leaves me on the profile  page. So instead of moving to path `"/"`, it leaves me on `"/profile"`.

Well I have tried reviewing the code, maybe something wrong or old.
But I haven't seen any progress in there.

Heres the code that governs the logic:

Redux:

```js
export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: {
    user: null,
  },
  reducers: {
    login: ( state, action ) => {
      state.user = action.payload;
    },
    logout: (state) => {
      state.user = null;
    }
  },
});
```

```
function App() {
  const user = useSelector(selectUser);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((userAuth) => {
      if (userAuth) {
        // logged in
        dispatch(login({
          uid: userAuth.uid,
          email: userAuth.email,
        }))
      } else {
        // logged out
        dispatch(logout())
      }
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <BrowserRouter>
        {!user ? (
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<LoginScreen />} /> 
          </Routes>
        ) : (
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/profile" element={<ProfileScreen/> } />
            <Route exact path="/" element={<HomeScreen />} />
          </Routes>
        )}
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  )
}
```

this is the code that governs the actual action:

```
<button
  onClick={()=>auth.signOut()}
  className="profileScreen_SignOut"
>
  Sign Out
</button>
```

Comment: Don't conditionally render your routes. Instead implement appropriate [route protection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66289280/8690857) based on user authentication. What does the `logout` action do? Can you [edit] to include a complete [mcve] that includes the Redux code that updates the `user` variable that is selected?

Comment: Doen it, I think

Comment: In case you missed it, or just haven't taken the full [tour] yet (*you earn a badge BTW*), there are 100% completely optional actions one can take after [someone answers](/help/someone-answers) that helps rate and curate content on the site.

Answer (score 0):

When a user logs out there is nothing redirecting them back to a valid route, namely the login route so they can reauthenticate again. It's a bit of an anti-pattern to conditionally render routes you want to protect access to. Create a route protection component that reads the `user` state and conditionally renders the protected content ***or*** a redirect to a safe route, e.g. an unprotected route like a login page.

Example:

```js
export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: {
    user: undefined // <-- initially undefined, let Firebase decide
  },
  reducers: {
    login: ( state, action ) => {
      state.user = action.payload;
    },
    logout: (state) => {
      state.user = null;
    }
  },
});
```

```
import { Outlet, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const PrivateRoutes = () => {
  const user = useSelector(selectUser);

  if (user === undefined) {
    return null; // or loading indicator/spinner/etc
  }

  return user
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
};
```

```js
function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((userAuth) => {
      if (userAuth) {
        // logged in
        dispatch(login({
          uid: userAuth.uid,
          email: userAuth.email,
        }));
      } else {
        // logged out
        dispatch(logout());
      }
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/login" element={<LoginScreen />} />

          <Route element={<PrivateRoutes />}>
            <Route path="/" element={<HomeScreen />} />
            <Route path="/profile" element={<ProfileScreen/> } />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If the user logs out while on route `"/"` or `"/profile"` they will be redirected to `"/login"` to log in again.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
But I'm a little confused. 
Where do you suggest to put the "import{Outlet, Navigate}" etc...?

Comment: @Jak Wherever you decide to declare/define the `PrivateRoutes` component. It could be a standalone file, or you could declare it above `App` where it is used, or anywhere in your project where it makes sense for the project's organization. Does this make sense?

Comment: I have done as you suggested. But still it does not redirect me to "/"
It still leaves me on "/profile"
Any other suggestions? 
Do you need me to update the code and show you what I have done?

Comment: @Jak Check this running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-no-route-is-found-95msmh), the redirection from `"/profile"` to `"/login"` works when logging out and updating the `user` state. Are you trying to navigate from protected route `"/profile"` to protected route `"/"`? Feel free to fork this sandbox and add more of your actual code to see if you can reproduce the issue that we could then inspect live.

Comment: what im trying is when im loggin off, the userAuth should kick in, and then if there isnt any user, i should be redirected to login screen which is on "/" path.
Im following a video toturial on youtube, and im doing as instructed, but im stuck on this point.
its works for the guy that shows the toturial and not for me.
I really appreciate your help btw.
thnx

Comment: @Jak Youtube tutorials and web blogs are notoriously always outdated it seems. When a user logs out, if they are on a protected route, when the components rerender because the `user` state was updated the route guard will redirect them off the route. Are you still trying to render `Home` and `Login` components on the same route?

Comment: il post it on codesanbox, so you could see my modification.

Comment: @Jak Sounds good. That's usually my next request, so we can inspect it live. Just ping me again here with a link to the sandbox if/when it is ready.

Comment: https://rb.gy/3w2ed
I have added another app.js, and added the most of the files that are necessary for the logic. I wont be on for the couple of hours.
But in 3-4 hours I will be on again.

Comment: @Jak Ok, taking a look now. So should the sandbox be rendering the `App` component exported from `app.js` (*not App.js*)?

Comment: @Jak Sorry, I don't think the sandbox you linked is very usable. Just to get things running I've had to comment out almost all of the imports in various files and the `user` state selection and the `auth` imports and usage. I'm not sure what it would be capable of demonstrating.

Comment: So whats your suggestion?

Comment: @Jak I just need to see a ***running*** example of the code you are using that produces the issue you are seeing. The routing and auth redirection is working as I'd expect in the sandbox I provided you. We just need to find what the difference is.

Comment: Oh I see, ok.
So I will update the entire project in the sandbox

Comment: @Jak Yes, exactly. Sorry if that initial request was unclear.

Comment: So yeah it is now up and running.
Somehow I messed up.
Its my first big project.
So im sorry for my screw ups..
Every file that I could load up there, I did. Hope you could help me solve this mess

Comment: @Jak Ok, so in your sandbox you are *still* conditionally rendering routes and haven't implemented logic to redirect unauthenticated users to `"/login"`. You *might* be able to issue redirects when the auth changes in the `useEffect` hook, but this doesn't actually prevent access to routes/content you'd like to protect. Try the solution I suggest with the `PrivateRoutes` layout route component. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-no-route-is-found-forked-d5xsvc?file=/src/app.js

Comment: @Jak Welcome, glad to help. Has this answer helped otherwise resolve the "route not found" issue?

Comment: So I tried to copy the code you made but I got allot of errors.
Can I send you these errors msgs?

Comment: @Jak Yes, of course.

Comment: Firstly I would like to say that Im new to react.

secondly, if you have any good ideas where to learn react, modern react, from scratch I would really appreciate it.

Thirdlu errros:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'basename' of 'react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useContext(...)' as it is null.
Uncaught Error: useRoutes() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'basename' of 'react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useContext(...)' as it is null.

Comment: @Jak Ah, that was in your sandbox, I also had to fix it. In `app.js` change the export from `export default App();` to `export default App;` so you are not trying to call the `App` component as a function.

Comment: @Jak I feel I learned React the hard way, coming from a strictly C/C+/C++/Java education into web development, trying to apply OOP design patterns to React I basically did everything the wrong way a 100 times before learning the right way. I've probably spent hours upon hours reading and rereading the React docs. What really helped me though was spending time answering posts here on SO where I got to read ***tons*** of *other* people's code and seeing the issues and problems they faced.

Comment: But these errors occur after I copied the code you wrote and paste it over my app.js
So how is that possible? if you fixed it, then it should be fixed for me aswell. no?

Comment: @Jak Oh, sorry, I should have looked more closely at the error(s) you shared, there was a similar Redux-related error regarding the `useContext` hook. I also moved the `BrowserRouter` to the index file when I was testing out some functionality. Just make sure there is a router higher in the ReactTree than any `Link`, `Route`, etc, components that need to have the routing context available to them in order to function.

Comment: ok so it works again.
Do you have a suggetsion how to create a code that when ever the user logs in, he then moves to the homeScreen. and if he logs out, he then will be moved to the login screen again?

Comment: @Jak You can use `navigate(/* path to home screen */);` in the login function after successful authentication. You can also protect the `"/login"` route from authenticated users, e.g. similar but opposite of `PrivateRoutes` in my answer, where it redirects authenticated users to the home screen (*see this [post](/a/76937138/8690857) for example*). Being on a private route and logging out should already handle redirecting users to `"/login"` to authenticate again.

Comment: So I just wanted to say that logoff works!! 
Thnx.
But, the login mechanism does not work.
Well it does, but not completely, It does log the user in, but It does not move the user to the homeScreen.
Do you have any suggestion to what may have cause that?
Because before I asked the question it worked the other way around.
It did move me to the homeScreen but did not move me from the profileScreen to the login screen

Comment: @Jak Yes, my previous [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77349927/react-redux-no-route-is-found#comment136401844_77350098) makes the suggestion for you to use the `navigate` function in your login handler to redirect the user back to the page they were trying to access or for you to create another route protection component for the "login" page so authenticated users are redirected off it. If you need help with either of these can you edit your post to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant app code?