# Cannot navigate in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

This is my code to happen when submit button is clicked

```js
const location = useLocation();
const from = location.state?.from?.pathname || "/";

// The above lines are perfectly fine in the parent function

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  loginDetails.userName = user;
  loginDetails.password = pwd;

  try {
    const response = await axios.post(
      LOGIN_URL,
      JSON.stringify({ user, pwd }),
      {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        withCredentials: true,
      }
    );

    const accessToken = response?.data?.accessToken;
    const roles = response?.data?.roles;
    setAuth({ user, pwd, roles, accessToken });
    setUser('');
    setPwd('');

    navigate(from, {replace:true});
  } catch (err) {
    if (!err?.response) {
      console.log(err);
      setErrMsg('No Server Response');
    } else if (err.response?.status === 400) {
      setErrMsg('Missing Username or Password');
    } else if (err.response?.status === 401) {
      setErrMsg('Unauthorized');
    } else {
      setErrMsg('Login Failed');
    }
    errRef.current.focus();
  }
};
```

This is my Router.js responsible for routing the pages

```
const Router = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Login />}>
          {/* Public route */}
          <Route path='login' element={<Login />} />
          {/* Private routes */}
          {/* The below is for the user */}
          <Route path='grievance/*' element={<RequireAuth allowedRoles={[ROLES.User]} />}>
            <Route element={<Grievance />} />
          </Route>
          {/* The below is for the admin */}
          <Route path='admin/*' element={<RequireAuth allowedRoles={[ROLES.Admin]} />}>
            <Route element={<Admin />} />
          </Route>
          {/* catch everything else */}
          <Route path='*' element={<Missing />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

This is my `RequireAuth.js` responsible for checking authorization of the person

```
const RequireAuth = ({ allowedRoles }) => {
  const { auth } = useAuth();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  console.log("Here in require auth");

  if (auth?.roles?.find(role => allowedRoles?.includes(role))) {
    console.log("for outlet");
    return <Outlet />;
  } else if (auth?.user) {
    console.log("for unauthorized");
    navigate("/unauthorized", { replace: true });
    return null;
  } else {
    console.log("Authlogin");
    navigate("/login", { replace: true });
    return null;     
  }
};
```

And the console has the log of only the "navigating to grievance page" and nothing else from  `RequireAuth.js`, and in backend of my code everything is running fine and in the frontend I am responded with all the data correctly. But I am unable to navigate from one page to the other Please help me in this

`Grievance` is not rendering though it is navigating to    `"/grievance"`. I just checked that.

**If you are asking for my useAuth(). the code is below**

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

const AuthContext = createContext({});

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState({});
  // console.log("auth=",auth);
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ auth, setAuth }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default AuthContext;
```

Even after going through the post suggested by the comment, I still could not figure out what went wrong

Comment: Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66289280/8690857 If not, then can you [edit] to provide a complete [mcve] and more debugging details? What is the "auth" code/logic, etc?

Comment: No it did not help me I used the logic navigate(from,replace:true) but still of no use I did not use it in useeffect but I used it in on the submit of login page and if success, navigae(from, replace:true) but it still did not work

Comment: Can you help me in this? I used the same method that was mentioned in your link in my previous project which is currently not there due to the loss of data. There it worked perfectly fine, but now why is it not?  Now, after the suggested changes even the navigation is not happening i.e., in my path, no change is occurring

Comment: Another edit : I kept my BrowseRouter wrapping everything in index.js

Comment: So what exactly is the issue then? Please [edit] to provide debugging details and a complete [mcve] that includes the authentication state/logic you are using. If you can, see if you can also create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live.

Comment: Even navigation is not happening with the current code, check my code if I need to keep navigate in useefect and also when I navigated directly to a path, the component required is not rendering like /grievance login component persists and no much debug statements are required as the requireAuth is nit called after navigate is called

Comment: yeah,I understood but how to render <Login/> as root component?

Comment: So you still want `Login` to render on `"/"`? or do you want `"/"` to redirect to `"/login"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the issue here is that you are rendering `Login` as a layout route component on the root `"/"` parent route and that `Login` doesn't render an `Outlet` component for the nested routes to render out their `element` content. This appears to agree with the behavior you describe where the URL path changes to `"/grievance"` but the `Login` component is still rendered and the nested route isn't reached and so you get none of the logged output from your `RequireAuth` component.

Remove `element={<Login />}` from the root route so an `Outlet` component is rendered by default. If you don't have any specific "home page" content to display on path `"/"` then you can remove this route entirely and let the `path="*"` handle it.

Example:

```
const Router = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        {/* Public route */}
        <Route path='login' element={<Login />} />

        {/* Private routes */}
        {/* The below is for the user */}
        <Route element={<RequireAuth allowedRoles={[ROLES.User]} />}>
          <Route path='grievance' element={<Grievance />} />
        </Route>

        {/* The below is for the admin */}
        <Route element={<RequireAuth allowedRoles={[ROLES.Admin]} />}>
          <Route path='admin' element={<Admin />} />
        </Route>

        {/* catch everything else */}
        <Route path='*' element={<Missing />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

The `RequireAuth` component should render the `Navigate` component instead of using the `navigate` function in the render return directly. It should also forward the current `location` so the `Login` component has a `from` value to use from route state.

```
const RequireAuth = ({ allowedRoles = [] }) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const { auth } = useAuth();

  if (auth?.roles?.some(role => allowedRoles.includes(role))) {
    return <Outlet />;
  } else if (auth?.user) {
    return <Navigate to="/unauthorized" replace />;
  } else {
    return <Navigate to="/login" replace state={{ from: location }} />;     
  }
};
```

Comment: I want to render Login on both the / and /login

Comment: @KonduruPremsai That's fine, you can render a `<Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/login" replace />} />` or `<Route path="/" element={<Login />} />`, but then you'll need to remove `"/"` as a fallback referrer value in `Login`, e.g. remove `"/"` from `const from = location.state?.from?.pathname || "/";`, so you don't create a render loop where the `Login` route results in redirecting back to itself. Does this make sense?

Comment: yeah, thank you