# How to stay on the protected route, after refreshing page in React router 6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I created a protected route in react-router 6 like so:
Protected.js:

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom'

const Protected = () => {
    const { isAuthenticated } = useSelector(state => state.auth)
    return (
        isAuthenticated ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to='login' />
    )
}
export default Protected
```

And added it like so:
App.js:

```
export default function App() {

  useEffect(() => {
    store.dispatch(loadUser())
  }, [])

  return (
<Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
<Route element={<Protected />}>
    <Route path="profile" element={<Profile />} />
</Route>
```

And it works, the first time the profile page loads. But, when I refresh it, it takes me back to home page.
Any ideas as to how to stay on profile page after refresh?

This is store.js:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { productsReducer } from './reducers/product'
import { authReducer, userReducer } from './reducers/user'

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        products: productsReducer,
        auth: authReducer,
        user: userReducer
    }
})

export default store
```

This is authReducer.js:

```
export const authReducer = (state = { user: {} }, action) => {

switch (action.type) {
    case LOGIN_REQ:
    case REGISTER_REQ:
    case LOAD_USER_REQ:
        return {
            isAuthenticated: false,
            loading: true
        }
    case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
    case REGISTER_SUCCESS:
    case LOAD_USER_SUCCESS:
        return {
            ...state,
            loading: false,
            isAuthenticated: true,
            user: action.payload
        }
    case LOGOUT_SUCCESS:
        return {
            loading: false,
            isAuthenticated: false,
            user: null,
        }
    case LOGIN_FAIL:
    case REGISTER_FAIL:
        return {
            ...state,
            loading: false,
            isAuthenticated: false,
            user: null,
            error: action.payload
        }
    case LOAD_USER_FAIL:
        return {
            loading: false,
            isAuthenticated: false,
            user: null,
            error: action.payload
        }
    case LOGOUT_FAIL:
        return {
            ...state,
            error: action.payload
        }
    case CLEAR_ERRORS:
        return {
            ...state,
            error: null
        }
    default:
        return state
}
}
```

This is userActions.js:

```
export const loadUser = () => async dispatch => {

try {
    dispatch({ type: LOAD_USER_REQ })

    const { data } = await axios.get('/api/profile')

    dispatch({
        type: LOAD_USER_SUCCESS,
        payload: data.user
    })

} catch (error) {
    dispatch({
        type: LOAD_USER_FAIL,
        // payload: error.response.data.message
    }) // TODO (this only disables err msg on login page (re)load,
    // but doesn't solve the problem: GET http://.../api/profile 401 (Unauthorized))
}
}
```

Comment: Does `isAuthenticated` take a bit of time to be "computed"? Does this help answer your question? [How to create a protected route with React-Router-DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66289280/8690857) Can you [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of all the relevant code?

Comment: Just tried those solutions, but none helped.

Comment: Can you update this post to provide more details and context then?

Comment: Of course. What details?
The context is as follows: when a user logs in, navigates to his profile page, and refreshes it, he should be redirected back to the profile page, not to home page. If user is not logged in, then he can't access his profile page.

Comment: Can you share your Redux code? The auth slice/reducer, the store creation, any related thunks/asynchronous actions, etc. I think we need to see what goes into setting/updating this `isAuthenticated` value.

Comment: Just added store.js
When U mentioned it, I am not sure if it's correct.

Comment: Can you add also the `authReducer` and anything else related to that state, e.g. the actions, the reducer code, etc?

Comment: Added that too.

Comment: So it appears that `state.auth.isAuthenticated` is initially falsey and it takes the `loadUser` and `LOAD_USER_SUCCESS ` actions being dispatched in order for a user to be considered authenticated. Following the suggested implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66289280/8690857) handles this. If you need more help than this can you include also where and how the app is dispatching the `loadUser` action?

Comment: Yes, it's dispatched in App.js, in useEffect hook.

Comment: In `Protected` add a `if (isAuthenticated === undefined) return null;` before the main return. This is so `Protected` "waits" until `isAuthenticated` is set true or false after `loadUser` is dispatched and completes.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentaly deleted this post. Managed to undelete it, though.
Seems that: if (!isAuthenticated) return null have done the magic.
Thanks a loads :)

Comment: ...While we are at it, I would like to ask one more thing.
If I uncomment: payload: error.response.data.message in userActions.js I get the error message on login page (re)load ("Login first to access this resource"). This, I guess, is a consequence of problem with loadUser - when i load the app's homepage, I get the error in console: 
GET http://.../api/profile 401 (Unauthorized)).

Comment: I'm not really sure if there's a question in there. You uncomment the payload in the failure case and the see the error rendered to the UI. Are you expecting to see error messages rendered to the UI in these cases?

Comment: P.S. Would like to rate helpful content. Not sure how to do it, though. Could U give me a hint? :)

Comment: No, I don't expect user to see "Login first to access this resource", when he navigates to login page. As if he tried to access his profile. To be clear, the login page loads as it should, but this message is not suposed to pop-up at that moment. Like I said, I think the true manifestation of the problem is: when i load the app's homepage, I get the error in console: GET http://.../api/profile 401 (Unauthorized)). Is this expected (after all, the user should be unauthorized if not logged in)?

Comment: It's difficult say without seeing a more complete overall code example. It may be worth it to create a new post specific to the error rendering you are seeing, with a [mcve] of course. If you do this feel free to ping me in another comment here with a link to the post and I can take a look when available.

Comment: And rating content == voting, if so inclined. It's not mandatory by any means, but it is generally considered healthy user action.

Comment: Great!
Thanks for everything.

Comment: Finally! if (loading || isAuthenticated === undefined) return null
in Protected.js did the trick for all protected routes.