# Two React Routes behave differently. Can someone please explain, I've been looking for answers for days

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have these two routes in my `App` component, The `user` property is from a context. When the user log in, their email gets saved in local storage, then I try to read it in my context.

**UserContext.js**

```js
const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
   if (!localStorage.getItem("user")) {
      return;
   } else {
      setUser(localStorage.getItem("user"));
   }   
}, []);
```

**App.jsx**

```js
const { user } = useContext(UserContext);

<Route
   path="create"
   element={user ? <Create /> : <Navigate to="/login" />}
/>
<Route
   path="dashboard"
   element={user ? <Dashboard /> : <Navigate to="/login" />}
/>
```

If the user is not logged in they can't visit those two routes and should be directed to `login` page, that works. However when user is logged in, I can go to `/dashboard` and it's fine, **BUT** if I go to `/create`, React redirects to `/dashboard`. It's wrecking my head, why is that? what am I missing? Thank you all

This happens when I manually type the url in address bar or I refresh the `/create` page. Even though I am logged in I get redirected to `/dashboard`. Thanks

**UPDATE**

I think what is happening is that redirect happens before `user` value is set. if I set the `user` value directly from the local storage, like this: `const user = localStorage.getItem('user')`, then it works the way it should. But then again it is hurting my brain because this happens only on `/create` page.

Comment: What is `user` in this code snippet? You may need to [edit] to provide a complete [mcve] so we can see what any code is doing around this code. That said, when you manually update the URL in the address bar you are reloading the entire page and app, so any state is reset if it isn't persisted somewhere.

Comment: @DrewReese I updated the code, and I believe you're right it's about the state. Thanks

Comment: Do you have some code somewhere redirecting to `"/dashboard"` when the page is reloaded?

Comment: @DrewReese, No, on my create page I have some logic for create a blog post that is all inside a handler function, so nothing triggers on page load. What is strange to me is that I have more or less the same code on `/create` and `/dashboard`, but only `/create` page redirects wrongly. Anyways it's okay, I'll find another way. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial `user` state is `null`, e.g. a falsey value, so when you are manually changing the URL in the address bar the page is reloaded and any `user` state is reset and the initial `null` value is used for the initial render cycle until the `useEffect` hook runs and reads from localStorage.

Use a lazy state initializer function to provide the initial `user` state from localStorage, and use the `useEffect` hook to persist any `user` state changes to localStorage.

Example:

```js
const [user, setUser] = useState(() => {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
});

useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));
}, [user]);
```

To handle protecting routes/content then see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66289280/8690857) for implementing standard route protection.

Answer (score -1):

It appears that you might be using relative paths in your route configurations, which can cause issues when navigating directly to URLs. Instead, use absolute paths starting with a forward slash /.

```
<Route
   path="/create"
   element={user ? <Create /> : <Navigate to="/login" />}
/>
<Route
   path="/dashboard"
   element={user ? <Dashboard /> : <Navigate to="/login" />}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you but nope, that didn't fix it. I added the `/` but still behaves the same way

Comment: This isn't the issue. All routes are built ***relative*** the any parent routes. In fact, specifying absolute paths can break this abstraction even... though if this was the case there would be an warning/error regarding it.

Comment: If the issue persists, consider checking if your routes are nested or if there are conflicting route configurations elsewhere in your app. Additionally, make sure there are no conflicting logic or redirects in the Create component. Showing more code may help

Answer (score -1):

It seems like there might be a redirect set up on the login page, and if the user is already logged in, it's automatically redirecting to the dashboard. To address this issue, consider using a query parameter for each page.

***I guess what is happening then is when you go to the create page it checks for a user but for the first time user data may not be available hence react will route you to the login page but you're already login hence in the login page you had set that if user login then redirect to dashboard. hence you'll be redirected to the dashboard every time.***

**Redirect Logic on Login Page:**
Check if there is redirection logic on the login page that automatically directs a logged-in user to the dashboard. Ensure this logic aligns with your desired behavior.

**Use Query Parameters for Each Page:**
Instead of relying solely on the user's login status for redirection, consider using query parameters for each page. This provides a more explicit way to handle redirection based on specific conditions.

**Debugging:**
If the issue persists, use debugging tools or add console logs to trace the flow of authentication and redirection logic.

**Provide Additional Details:**
If you encounter challenges or need more assistance, share additional details about your authentication setup, including how the login redirection is implemented