# How to get react router v6 to load correct component after authentication in single page application?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, google-oauth

When a user is authenticated via google auth (`onAuthStateChanged`), sometimes the correct component for the root path is not loaded and I'll get a blank page.

I'm trying to get different components to load in the `"/"` route, depending on the state of `user`:

`<Login />` = not authenticated

`<Home />` = `user.role` is user

`<Admin />` = `user.role` is admin

In my actual code, I do have protected routes that check the status of `user` from the `AuthContext`, but I simplified the code for this question.

I've tried putting a `<Navigate to="/" replace />` in both the Login.jsx file and the AuthContext.jsx file. I've already tried adding a `location.reload()` call, but it caused an infinite loop.

I understand that when I set state (`setUser`), that state changes are asynchronous and only on the next render will React update it.

When I put a `console.log` statement in to the code (for debugging), it works just fine.

Also, if I manually refresh the page (when it's blank), the correct component loads just fine.

All of the routing works perfectly except for the jump from the `Login` page to the home page when the auth status changes. Even the logout functionality works smoothly, bringing the user back to the `Login` page.

What's the best practice for re-rendering the root component via react router 6 after the auth state changes?

AuthContext.jsx

```
import { useState, useEffect, createContext } from "react";
import { auth } from "./firebaseInit";

export const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthContextProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect( () => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged( async (auth_user) => {
      if (auth_user) {
        if (auth_user.emailVerified) {
          // api call to grab user data
          setUser(auth_user);

          // SHOULD I PUT THIS HERE?
          // return <Navigate to="/" replace />
        }
      }
    });

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    }

  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{user}}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Login.jsx

```
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from "../../backend/firebaseInit";

export default function Login() {
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(e.currentTarget);
    
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, data.get('email'), data.get('password') )
    .then( async (userCredential) => {
       const auth_user = userCredential.user;
       if (auth_user) {
         // ADDING THIS MAKES IT WORK
         //console.log('i am about to navigate');

         // SHOULD I PUT THIS HERE?
         //return <Navigate to="/" replace />;
       }
     })
     .catch((err) => {
       console.log(err.toString());
     })
  };

  return (
    <Container >
      <Box>
        // login form
      </Box>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Routes.jsx

```
import { AuthContext } from './AuthContext';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from'react-router-dom';

export default function ConvuRouter() {
  const {user} = useContext(AuthContext);

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={user ? ( user.role === 'admin' ? <Admin /> : (user.role === 'user' ? <Home /> : <Login /> ) ) : <Login /> } />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

Comment: What component are you trying to get to load after authentication? There's only the one route so it's not like you can navigate elsewhere. Can you [edit] to clarify in better detail what the problem is? Does [how to create a protected route with react-router-dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66289122/how-to-create-a-protected-route-with-react-router-dom) help answer your question?

Comment: @DrewReese : Thanks so much for your help. Your many comments on other posts have helped me so much!  I'm trying to get different components to load in the `"/"` route, depending on the state of `user`:

`<Login />` = not authenticated

`<Home />` = `user.role` is user

`<Admin />` = `user.role` is admin

Comment: It seems that setting the `user` state in the `AuthContext` ought to be enough here. What about something like this on the route then: `<Route path="/" element={user?.role === 'admin' ? <Admin /> : user?.role === 'user' ? <Home /> : <Login />} />`?

Comment: @DrewReese: Thanks so much! Your change and then deleting `<Navigate to="/" replace />` from the login page did the trick.