# react useRoutes redirects to page on refresh when it shoudn't

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm using react and i have this routes

```
import React from 'react';
import Dashboard from './pages/Dashboard';
import MainLayout from './layouts/MainLayout';
import Management from './pages/Management';
import AdminForecast from './pages/AdminForecast';
import LogIn from './pages/LogIn';
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import BrandForecast from './pages/BrandForecast';
import ProductForecast from './pages/ProductForecast';

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <Navigate to="forecast" replace={true} />,
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    element: <LogIn />,
  },
  {
    path: 'forecast/dashboard',
    element: (
      <MainLayout>
        <Dashboard />
      </MainLayout>
    ),
  },
  {
    path: 'forecast/management-growth',
    element: (
      <MainLayout>
        <Management />
      </MainLayout>
    ),
  },
  {
    path: 'forecast/brand',
    element: (
      <MainLayout>
        <BrandForecast />
      </MainLayout>
    ),
  },
  {
    path: 'forecast/product/:id',
    element: (
      <MainLayout>
        <ProductForecast />
      </MainLayout>
    ),
  },
  {
    path: 'forecast',
    element: <MainLayout />,
  },
  {
    path: 'admin',
    element: <MainLayout />,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'forecast',
        element: <AdminForecast />,
      },
    ],
  },
];

export default routes;
```

Which is rendered like this

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import routes from './routes';
import { useRoutes } from 'react-router-dom';
import AuthService from './services/auth.service';
import { useAuth } from './providers/AuthProvider';

function App() {
  const { setIsLoggedIn} = useAuth();
  useEffect(() => {
    AuthService.LoginCheck()
      .then((data: any) => {
        setIsLoggedIn(true);
      })
      .catch(() => {
        setIsLoggedIn(false);
      });
  }, []);

  const content = useRoutes(routes);
  return content;
}

export default App;
```

I'm not using any server side routing like express and i don't need it for the purpose of this project, the routing works correctly but when i'm in 'forecast/management-growth' or 'forecast/brand' or any page like that and i refresh, i get redirected to the 'forecast' page instead of staying in the current page. How can i fix it?

Comment: The only redirect I see in the code you provided is from `"/"` to `"/forecast"`. Do you have some other code elsewhere that also handles navigation/redirection logic? Maybe something referencing something from the auth context? Can you [edit] to include more complete details and a complete [mcve]?

Comment: Thanks, i was looking for other navigate instances and i found the bug. In the login it redirects to forecast and for some reason when i refresh it renders login first

Comment: You found the bug, do you still need help with it?

Comment: Now i have a new problem because the login redirects to forecast and i don't have a way to check the navigation history to redirect to the correct page. do you know a way to do it?

Comment: Are you referring to the `"/login"` route and the `Login` component are redirecting to `"/forecast"`? Can you [edit] to include the `Login` code that is redirecting? Maybe also include that `MainLayout` component that is used in several places? Does my answer here for [How to create a protected route with react-router-dom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66289280/8690857) help?

Comment: In the end I used localstorage to save the last route link so that when it refreshes it redirects to that page instead of a default one, thanks for your help though!